# How to parse the JSON object in ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Iam getting a JSON response as

```
{
 "title": "Some title",
 "link": "http://google.com",
 "desc": "Some description",
 "items": [{"title":"some title"}]
```

}

I used $ajax to get the response

```
$.ajax({

                url : url,                          
                type: 'post',                   
                dataType:'jsonp',                   
                success : function(data) {  
                     console.log(json)
                }

                });

        };
```

Its gives me a 'Invalid Label' error. Since the response is coming from a different server should i use JSONP? I googled it and many suggested to ParseJSON. But how to parse it, as the console.log is not firing.

Comment: Should the extra `};` at the end of your code sample be there?

Comment: Its the facebook feed iam trying to pull... here is the url ... http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=163276271689&format=json

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSONP call with invalid label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935438/jsonp-call-with-invalid-label)

Comment: If they don't support JSONP, you cannot make an Ajax call. You have to make an Ajax call to your server which in turns can make a call to Facebook.

Comment: So how can i show the data from the feed?

Comment: Do you have any link to some official documentation? As I said, you'd have to make the call server side...

Comment: Am trying to pull the Facebook feed... facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=163276271689&format=json

Comment: I understood that. I explained you why it is not possible and what you could do to make it work. Please read about JSONP, maybe you'll understand it then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 1):

The `data` variable being passed into the success function is the response. `console.log(json)` will be undefined, because the variable `json` doesn't exist.

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,                          
    type: 'post',                   
    dataType:'json',                   
    success : function(data) {  
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: True — there's an extra `};` at the end of the code sample above that could also be a syntax error.

Comment: No, the problem is that the server returns JSON and not JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type to `json`, and add `&callback=?` to your URL

Comment: jQuery is adding `&callback=...` automatically if you choose `jsonp` as data type... why should it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that ajax request returns "data" (Looks like it returns).

```
{ "title": "Some title",
  "link": "http://google.com",
  "desc": "Some description",
  "items": [{"title":"some title"}]
}.
```

You could use this format as an associative array. Just like :

```
var title=data["title"]; //this will give you "some title"
var items=data["items"]; //this will give you a list of items.
var item_title=items["title"]; //process list of items similarly
```

etc.